# Use setHighlighted in the UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Do I need to subclass UITableViewCell to use setHighlighted? I am trying to overlay an image on top of my cell between the moment that it is tapped and the moment the action happens. I used to do it by using setHighlighted in a custom UITableViewCell xib but I redid my app using custom cells straight from the sotryboard. It seems like over kill to subclass the whole cell only to be able to use setHighlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you could try using the UITableView delegate methods:

```
tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:
```

I would guess that subclassing the UITableViewCell and overriding setHighlighted might offer better performance though.